# What is the correct order of operations for one-time pad cipher when using subtraction and mod 10 arithmetic?

Tags: encryption, one-time-pad, decryption

What would be the proper order of operations for OTP encryption/decryption when using subtraction and mod 10? E.g. **P - K = C** or **K - P = C**

Most of the sources I have seen do not cover this topic or I didn't grasp the principles behind this encryption well enough. From what I gather it shouldn't matter as long as the pad key numbers (**K**) are truly random.

For instance:

```
PLAINCODE:  65417
OTP PAD(-): 47757
-----------------
CIPHER:     28760
```

**EDIT:**
From some tests I see that. When used for encryption, whether **P + K** or **K + P** to decrypt the original message you need to do **C - K**, otherwise **K - C** will not return **P**.
When used for encryption, **P - K** since **C + K** will return **P**, otherwise **K + C** will not return the original **plaincode**.

Can someone please explain whether using subtraction or addition for encryption one has a security advantage over the other.

Comment: Why the subtraction? The common and most intuitive method is addition for encryption, and subtraction only for decryption.   Irrelevant from a security perspective, but perhaps a little easier on the brain. Have you seen http://users.telenet.be/d.rijmenants/en/onetimepad.htm?    Probably the best resource on OTPs anywhere.

Comment: Hey. I did yeah. It is a really the best resource out there, but I didn't find an answer to my question there (I might have missed it). I just wanted to better understand the different variants of the OTP encryption and whether they are equal in terms of encryption strength.

Answer (score 3):

I advocate for $K-P\to C$ and $K-C\to P$ so that encryption and decryption are identical, as in the binary OTP. Each digit is processed modulo 10.

```
    OTP PAD K:  47757            OTP PAD K:  47757
  - PLAINTEXT:  65417          - CIPHERTEXT: 82340 
    -----------------            -----------------
  = CIPHERTEXT: 82340          = PLAINTEXT:  65417
```

---

Update: from functionality and security perspectives, $P-K\to C$ and $C+K\to P$ is perfectly fine; as well as $P+K\to C$ and $C-K\to P$. What I advocate has a single benefit: the same method/code is used for encryption and decryption.

The reason these three variants allow decryption and are perfectly secure is the same: the set $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ is a group under addition modulo $10$ (if the group is not commutative, we need to change $K-C\to P$ into $(-C)+K\to P$ ). Therefore, there is nothing to learn about $P$ from $C$ when not knowing $K$.

Comment: What about when different operations are performed for both encryption (P - K = C) and decryption (C + K = P).  Is there any benefit using one over the other?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the explanation! Makes perfect sense.